# Which type of "numbers" will require order 3 factors for its irreducible polynomial factorizations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, reference-request, soft-question, factoring

The complex numbers are famous for having the property of the fundamental theorem of algebra.

All polynomials have at least one root.

Together with being factor-able, this means we can factor every complex polynomial of degree n into a product of n linear factors. (For monic polynomials we can skip $k$)
$$p(z) = k\cdot \prod_{i=1}^n (z-z_i)$$

For real valued polynomials this is not true. We will there also need to allow polynomial factors of degree 2 to reach some irreducible expression.

So it is clear that there exist two possibilities of numbers : those whose polynomials are guaranteed reducible down to 1 and 2 degrees. But what about 3? Which type of numbers will require us to allow also third-degree polynomial factors to factor "completely"?

---

**Edit >** So to clarify, I am looking for a type of number so that for any polynomial with coefficients and variables in this set of numbers which I seek will be guaranteed to be able to factor it into factors of order 1,2 or 3 but never higher and that the case 3 by necessity happens for at least one polynomial.

We can always write :
$$p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^N c_kx^k = K \prod_i (c_{i3}x^3+c_{i2}x^2+c_{i1}x+c_{i0})$$

So that there exists at least one p for which there is at least one i so that $c_{i3} \neq 0$

But for some p, all the $c_{i3}$ and also $c_{i2}$ may be $0$.

Comment: Are you asking for a field with the property that every irreducible polynomial is of degree either $1$,$2$, or $3$, and has some of degree $3$?

Comment: I think that is what I am asking, but I have not studied very much abstract algebra.

Comment: Re: interpretation by @ArturoMagidin, [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16778/what-are-the-possible-sets-of-degrees-of-irreducible-polynomials-over-a-field) MO question suggests that a finite set of degrees for irreducible polynomials is impossible, unless it is $\{1\}$ or $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: I second the comment by @Amateur_Algebraist which follows from the Artin-Schreier Theorem. (The linked MO question discusses the more intricate question what infinite sets of possible degrees can occur.)

Comment: @m-stgt Have you tried methods of better accuracy than single or double point floating point arithmetics? Led it to any illumination?

Comment: @mathreadler -- Nope, I did not. I use pocket calculators with 10 digits mantissa (computing internally with 13 digits). As with a slide rule I restrain to use numeric results as source for insights/illuminations/enlightenment or misinterpretation (except prime factor decomposition or similar integer stuff). Thus, when I say "$x_0$ known by chance to the last digit", something like $\approx \sqrt{2}$ is excluded.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I wanted to cook up an explanation yesterday, but it turns out I don't even understand how to apply, say, Theorem 3.1 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf)... If the degree of irreducible polynomials is bounded from above, why must the algebraic closure be a finite extension?

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist: Well at least for perfect fields, where we have primitive elements, it goes like this: If the alg. closure has infinite degree, then for any given $n$ there is a finite subextension of degree higher than $n$. Find a primitive element for this, so its minimal polynomial will have to have that (higher than $n$) degree. -- Not sure about the workaround in the remaining case of purely inseparable extensions in positive characteristic, but there should be one ...

Comment: Originally I wanted to reconstruct the proof for arbitrary fields, and in this [thesis](https://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1445629/FULLTEXT01.pdf) I found an elementary proof of "**Lemma 7.2.** If the degrees of irreducible polynomials have an upper bound in $K[X]$, then $K$ is perfect." (Afterwards they use your argument.) But then I saw "numbers" in the question title :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll follow @TorstenSchoeneberg's line of reasoning. You asked about *numbers*, so I'll write about a field $k$ with $\mathrm{char } k = 0$.

- Such a field is [perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_field), i.e. every algebraic extension of it is [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension) (this is one of equivalent definitions).
- For separable extensions, we have the well-known [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem): any finite separable extension $K/k$ is generated by a single element, $K = k(\gamma)$.
- Any element $\alpha \in \overline{k}$ has a minimal polynomial of degree at most $n$, as the extension $\overline{k}/k$ is algebraic, and a minimal polynomial of a field element must be irreducible.

Now let the degree of (the minimal polynomial of) $\alpha \in \overline{k}$ be $n$ and prove that $k(\alpha) = \overline{k}$. Indeed, for $\beta \in \overline{k}$ we have $k(\alpha, \beta) = k(\gamma)$ for some $\gamma$ by the primitive element theorem, so $|k(\gamma)/k| \le n$ (the dimension as a vector space), but $k(\alpha)$ is contained in $k(\gamma)$, so they are equal and $\gamma, \beta \in k(\alpha)$.

This allows us to use

> [**Theorem 3.1**](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf) (Artin-Schreier). Let $C$ be algebraically closed with $F$ a subfield such that $1<[C:F]<\infty$. Then $C=F(i)$ where $i^2=−1$, and $F$ has characteristic $0$. Moreover, for $a\in F^\times$, exactly one of $a$ or $−a$ is a square in $F$, and every finite sum of nonzero squares in $F$ is again a nonzero square in $F$.

We conclude that *a field of characteristic $0$ that has bounded degree $d$ of irreducible polynomials has $d \le 2$*. The same holds without the a priori characteristic assumption (the bounded degree implies $\mathrm{char } k = 0$), but this is more difficult to prove.

Comment: So in other words (if I understand this right), this puts reasonable restrictions which are powerful enough to say that no such thing is possible for **any** integer >2?

Comment: @mathreadler Yes: if we have an irreducible polynomial of degree $k>2$, then there must exist an irr.pol. of *arbitrarily large* degree (but not necessarily *arbitrary* degree).